# VB6 'run-time error '424': Object Required' error

Tags: vb6, runtime-error

I am testing code before adding to an existing project. It ran perfectly when it looked like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell As Object
Dim m_EngineRun As Object

Sub main()

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set m_EngineRun = objShell.Exec("notepad.exe")
Dim objWMIService As Object
Dim colProcessList As Object

MsgBox m_EngineRun.ProcessID

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " & m_EngineRun.ProcessID)

If colProcessList.Count = 1 Then
    objShell.run "TASKKILL /F /IM " & m_EngineRun.ProcessID, , True
    MsgBox m_EngineRun.ProcessID & (" terminated")
Else
    MsgBox m_EngineRun.ProcessID & (" does not exist")
End If
End Sub
```

Then I added the lines below and it fails with the 424 error.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell As Object
Dim m_EngineRun As Object

'Added this line
Dim m_PID As Object

Sub main()

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set m_EngineRun = objShell.Exec("notepad.exe")

'And this line
Set m_PID = m_EngineRun.ProcessID
Dim objWMIService As Object
Dim colProcessList As Object

'And changed this one
MsgBox m_PID

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " & m_EngineRun.ProcessID)

If colProcessList.Count = 1 Then
    objShell.run "TASKKILL /F /IM " & m_EngineRun.ProcessID, , True
    MsgBox m_EngineRun.ProcessID & (" terminated")
Else
    MsgBox m_EngineRun.ProcessID & (" does not exist")
End If
End Sub
```

It is definitely the `Set m_PID = m_EngineRun.ProcessID` line that is the troublemaker.

I simply haven't been able to find an answer that pertains my specific issue. I feel like maybe m_PID shouldn't be an object? But if so, what should it be?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I thought it would be an object because I lack enough VB6 knowledge to know better :) What you have suggested worked beautifully! Thanks for your help. Shame I can't mark you as correct, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessID` isn't an object; it's an integer (the numeric process ID).

Remove the `As Object` and `Set`, and just assign directly:

```
Dim m_PID
'....
m_PID = m_EngineRun.ProcessID
```

It's probably better to not presume that everything is an object, because the vast majority of things you'll encounter are probably not. I'd start with not expecting an object unless you know otherwise, and then move to trying object if you encounter issues.